# Check if PHP function returns null or nothing

Tags: php, return-value

I have this code

```
 $return = $ep->$method($params);
 if ($return === null) {
  throw new Exception('Endpoint has no return value');
 }
 return $return;
```

Is there any way to distinguish between a method that returns `null` and a method that does not return anything?

Comment: Is this not working `if ($return === "") {}` ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not possible. When no return value is set the function automatically returns null.

Comment: Sorry, the correct answer is. Yes, you can modify and recompile the PHP source code. :P

Answer (score 1):

If the function doesn't return anything, then you should not test it's return value. You should know which functions are expected to return something or nothing at all - even if you're not the one who wrote them.

Comment: Normally, yes, but in this case the function is looked up dynamically.

Comment: Well then in the light of other answers and the info provided the only solution I foresee is PHP parsing it's own code and looking for the "return" keyword inside the function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP7’s return type declaration feature:

```
function a(): void {
    return null; // :(
}

function b(): void {
    // :)
}

function c(): void {
    return; // :)
}
```

Comment: You would have to use reflection to check the hinted return type - comparing `b() === null` is still true.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the function return another value? Boolean true possibly, and check for that or null.

Comment: I'm not always going to be the one writing the functions that are called

Comment: Extending the mixed type return value to further include boolean type data makes a loosely typed project looser.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ob_start();

echo trim($ep->$method($params));
$output = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

if (empty($output)) {
  throw new Exception('Endpoint has no return value');
}
return $return;
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this convoluted/hacky unexplained snippet improves/solves the situation.

Comment: @mickmackusa i guess there's only one way to find out ;)

Comment: Or you could bother to explain what your script does and give a compelling argument for why you believe this approach should be welcomed in a professional script by [edit]ing your answer.  Whether this this script delivers the desired behavior or not is not my concern.  Whether this is best practice is.

Comment: @mickmackusa If you are not happy with my answer, you can use the one that was accepted 14 years ago. I don't need to "argue" anything. Output buffering is a common PHP practice. I don't have to provide documentation for an <p> tag in a HTML question. This is a working solution. This is not convoluted nor hacky. If you have a better solution, feel free to share it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpectedly you could force your coder (you usually writes the code to another coder) to return array with no values if no return type, so if null returned it means he returns nothing, if he manually return [ null ] it means he returns null and knows what he's doing;

Comment: Almost that way.
Empty array allows you to detect is user returns nothing or want to return something.
The coding is about reduce incoming types to two-three types. When you write in functional paradigm, you cannot control the user callback returns certain type. So you make a convention that you notify him, if you return empty array = that is the same as you return nothing. If array contain one element - that is your return, even if you return array where first element is false/null, it is "payload".
When you write code in OOP you usually set return type to reduce count of IF statements.

Comment: And yes, you could wrap user callback in your OOP caller that checks is he returning exactly an array.

Usually there are two types, that means "correct and incorrect". OOP way is return single type and throw exception if incorrect, but then your code is filled up with catch statements that is not production way. Or maybe "not-prefer way", because exception is like "i later decide how to do"

But most of langs have no emptyness validation so return STRING means "word" and "" could be returned. Then you use something like return string|null, and your code must convert empty string to null.

Comment: The point of the topic - php always returns null even if no return statement. So you could check is returned type is non-empty array, otherwise - it has no return.

Answer (score 0):

If your method potentially returns string type data (such as an empty string) or `null`, then you will be able to accurately differentiate using a strict comparison because `$var === null` and `$var === ''` will not let you down.

If your method conditionally returns `void` (the absence of a return value), then trying to access the returned value will still be `null`, but I reckon it's not good design to have conditional/optional return values.

If you have a method which may return `null` or possibly another data type while still operating under predictable circumstances, then your only other professional option is to throw an exception (when something exceptional happens), then handle those occurrences somewhere up the call stack.

When you have valid data which is never possibly `null`, then I recommend that you return `null` as a clear differentiator/flag.  PHP has devoted functions and operators specifically built to handle null identification and coalescing.